# Shrinkwrap + Simple Deform Modifier Problem

Tags: mesh, modifiers, shrinkwrap, surface-deform

I am trying to make the letter "A" to sit on the surface of the plane which has active Wave and Simple Deform modifiers on. Initially, "A" and the plane were merged together and the unfolding worked exactly as expected, but now, I want "A" to slide just slightly down the plane as the unfolding happens.

I've tried every single combination that I could think but couldn't find the solution that would make the letter sit on the surface and bend together with the plane correctly.

Please help.
[image]

This is what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

This is what I am getting:
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe it would be simpler to put the A in the plane material?

Comment: Hi, if I understood you correctly, by doing that, I wouldn't have the control over A's movement, which I want to slide down

Comment: you can move an image texture

Comment: to achieve the animation you show, i'm not sure why you want to shrinkwrap the letter, just create your kind of sticker, put the A on it through its material, deform with a curve modifier?

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to reply. It's not that I want to use the shrinkwrap specifically, I just don't know a better way to do it. Can you please elaborate a bit more on what you mean by "put the A on it through its material". Thank you.

Comment: Here is what I see from the animation you show, it can be done with some curve modifiers: https://zupimages.net/up/23/42/nd3z.gif

Answer (score 1):

If you want a letter to be projected onto the surface of a plane, don't use a *Shrinkwrap* modifier, just use a texture:

[image]

As for the effect you show, create as many curves as you have planes, rotate 45° on Z, give your label object a *Curve* modifier with the curve as *Curve Object*:

[image]

Here is what you give if you move the curves:

[image]

If I create a test mesh, subdivide it with a grid and a *Knife Project Tool* operation, give it the same *Curve* modifier animation, and a *Solidify* modifier to give it thickness:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much once again for taking the time to reply. In the animation that I am trying to replicate "A" is a separate object because you can see that when the animation starts the tip of the letter is slightly outside the edge of the plane. Although the method you suggested works to unfold the plane it doesn't create the bevel on the letter itself, something that I was looking to recreate.

In the end, creating a high-res lattice and then shrinkwraping it to the unfolding plane and then using the Lattice modifier on the letter worked ok enough to accept the result and move on

Comment: If it's a separate object, just use a texture with a transparent background?

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong but using a texture won't give you this effect: https://picallow.com/goal-2/?usp_success=2&post_id=190849&form_id=27

However this is the result I was able to achieve with the lattice:
https://picallow.com/my-result/?usp_success=2&post_id=190855&form_id=27
The bevel is barely visible if at all but it is what it is...

Comment: I've given a try with a 3D letter, please see my edit

Comment: This looks great! But would the letter not deform if you would try to slide it down? If you could update the final gif with that small addition you got the right answer! :) Thank you in advance